# Can't exit while loop with scanf.(Run length decoding)

Tags: c

So here is a program that is supposed to implement run length decoding.
(E.g. 2T2Y -->TTYY)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
     int n,i;
     char elem;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     while ( (elem=getchar()) != EOF && elem != '\n'){
         for (i=0; i<n; i++){
             putchar(elem);
         }
         scanf("%d",&n);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The output is right although scanf ,keeps asking for input. I already tried adding scanf[^\n] without results. (I am looking for an alternative to dynamic memory allocation , thats the reason I did not use fgets or arrays).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are calling `scanf` in your while loop so yes, it keeps asking for input? or I didn't get something

Comment: I updated my answer with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop is not full ending before you try to check for '\n'. For the input "2T2Y", it will read the Y, print it twice, then try to scan for a 3rd int. That never comes. You need a check after the for loop for the next character either being a number or a \n and then break

Try this:

```
int main ()
{
 int n,i;
 int elem;
 scanf("%d",&n);
 while ( (elem=getchar()) != EOF && elem != '\n'){
   if(elem >= '1' && elem <= '9'){
     ungetc(elem, stdin);
     scanf("%d", &n);
   }
   else{
     for (i=0; i<n; i++){
       putchar(elem);
     }
   }    
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not familiar with the ungetc funtion that did the trick.

Comment: `char elem; ... 
 while ( (elem=getchar()) != EOF` is an infinite loop when `char` is unsigned and end-of-file occurs.  Use `int elem;`.